# issues about using async_write right after async_read_until

Tags: boost-asio, asyncsocket

My code is as follows:

```
boost::asio::streambuf b1;

boost::asio::async_read_until(upstream_socket_, b1, '@',
           boost::bind(&bridge::handle_upstream_read, shared_from_this(),
           boost::asio::placeholders::error,
           boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));


void handle_upstream1_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                            const size_t& bytes_transferred)
  {
     if (!error)
     {

       async_write(downstream_socket_,
          b2,
          boost::bind(&bridge::handle_downstream_write,
          shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));  
     }
     else
        close();
  }
```

According to the documentation of async_read_until, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html, 
After a successful async_read_until operation, the streambuf may contain additional data beyond the delimiter. An application will typically leave that data in the streambuf for a subsequent async_read_until operation to examine.

I know that the streambuf may contain additional data beyond the delimiter, but, in my case, will it write those additional data (the data beyond the char'@') to the downstream_socket_ inside the async_write operation? Or will async_write function be smart enough not to write those additional data until the next time the handle_upstream1_read function is being called?

According to the approaches in the documentation, the data in streambuf are stored in the istream first ( std::istream response_stream(&streambuf); )
and then put it into a string by using std::getline() funciton.

Do I really need to store the streambuf in istream first and then convert it into a string and then convert it back to char arrary (so that I can send the char array to the downstream_socket_  ) instead of just using the async_write to write the data( up to but not including the delimter, '@' ) to the downstream_socket_ ?

I prefer the second approach so that I don't need to make several conversion on the data. However, it seems that something is wrong when I tried the second approach.

My ideal case is that:

1. upstream_socket_ received xxxx@yyyy by using async_read_until
2. xxxx@ is written to the downstream_socket_
3. upstream_socket_ received zzzz@kkkk by using async_read_until
4. yyyyzzzz@ is written to the downstream_socket_

It seems that async_write operation still writes the data beyond the delimiter to the downstream_socket_. (but I am not 100% sure about this)

I appreciate if anyone can provide a little help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload3.html) overload being used is considered complete when all of the [`streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html)'s data, its input sequence, has been written to the WriteStream (socket).  It is equivalent to calling:

```cpp
boost::asio::async_write(stream, streambuf,
    boost::asio::transfer_all(), handler);
```

One can limit the amount of bytes written and consumed from the streambuf object by calling this [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload4.html) overload with the [`boost::asio::transfer_exactly`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_exactly.html) completion condition:

```cpp
boost::asio::async_write(stream, streambuf, 
    boost::asio::transfer_exactly(n), handler);
```

Alternatively, one can write directly from the streambuf's input sequence.  However, one will need to explicitly consume from the streambuf.

```cpp
boost::asio::async_write(stream,
    boost::asio::buffer(streambuf.data(), n), handler);
// Within the completion handler...
streambuf.consume(n);
```

Note that when the [`async_read_until()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html) operation completes, the completion handler's `bytes_transferred` argument contains the number of bytes in the streambuf's input sequence up to and including the delimiter, or `0` if an error occurred.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e7c923adfaee5b5) using both approaches.  The example is written using synchronous operations in an attempt to simplify the flow:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

// This example is not interested in the handlers, so provide a noop function
// that will be passed to bind to meet the handler concept requirements.
void noop() {}

/// @brief Helper function that extracts a string from a streambuf.
std::string make_string(
  boost::asio::streambuf& streambuf,
  std::size_t n)
{
  return std::string(
      boost::asio::buffers_begin(streambuf.data()),
      boost::asio::buffers_begin(streambuf.data()) + n);
}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
  tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);

  // Connect client and server sockets.
  acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, boost::bind(&noop));
  client_socket.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), boost::bind(&noop));
  io_service.run();

  // Mockup write_buffer as if it read "xxxx@yyyy" with read_until()
  // using '@' as a delimiter.
  boost::asio::streambuf write_buffer;
  std::ostream output(&write_buffer);
  output << "xxxx@yyyy";
  assert(write_buffer.size() == 9);
  auto bytes_transferred = 5;

  // Write to server.
  boost::asio::write(server_socket, write_buffer,
      boost::asio::transfer_exactly(bytes_transferred));
   // Verify write operation consumed part of the input sequence.
  assert(write_buffer.size() == 4);

  // Read from client.
  boost::asio::streambuf read_buffer;
  bytes_transferred = boost::asio::read(
      client_socket, read_buffer.prepare(bytes_transferred));
  read_buffer.commit(bytes_transferred);

  // Copy from the read buffers input sequence.
  std::cout << "Read: " << 
               make_string(read_buffer, bytes_transferred) << std::endl;
  read_buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);

  // Mockup write_buffer as if it read "zzzz@kkkk" with read_until()
  // using '@' as a delimiter.
  output << "zzzz@kkkk";
  assert(write_buffer.size() == 13); 
  bytes_transferred = 9; // yyyyzzzz@

  // Write to server.
  boost::asio::write(server_socket, buffer(write_buffer.data(),
      bytes_transferred));
  // Verify write operation did not consume the input sequence.
  assert(write_buffer.size() == 13);
  write_buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);

  // Read from client.
  bytes_transferred = boost::asio::read(
      client_socket, read_buffer.prepare(bytes_transferred));
  read_buffer.commit(bytes_transferred);

  // Copy from the read buffers input sequence.
  std::cout << "Read: " << 
               make_string(read_buffer, bytes_transferred) << std::endl;
  read_buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
}
```

Output:

```
Read: xxxx@
Read: yyyyzzzz@
```

---

A few other notes:

- The `streambuf` owns the memory, and `std::istream` and `std::ostream` use the memory.  Using streams may be a good idea when one needs to extract formatted input or insert formatted output.  For instance, when one wishes to read the string `"123"` as an integer `123`.
- One can directly access the streambuf's input sequence and iterate over it.  In the example above, I use [`boost::asio::buffers_begin()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffers_begin.html) to help construct a `std::string` by iterating over a streambuf's input sequence.

  ```cpp
  std::string(
      boost::asio::buffers_begin(streambuf.data()),
      boost::asio::buffers_begin(streambuf.data()) + n);
  ```
- A stream-based transport protocol is being used, so handle incoming data as a stream.  Be aware that even if the intermediary server reframes messages and sends `"xxxx@"` in one write operation and `"yyyyzzzz@"` in a subsequent write operation, the downstream may read `"xxxx@yyyy"` in a single read operation.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and comprehensive explanation, Tanner.
transfer_exactly(n) and streambuf.consume(n) are exactly what I want!
The reason why I stuck for such a long time is that I tried to use a single '@' char to act as an end tag symbol in my video stream data which is totally a dump idea

Comment: The example uses write() which I assume is the synchronous boost::asio::write(), correct?

Comment: @Dronz Yes. [Argument-dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) caused the compiler to select  `boost::asio::read()`, `boost::asio::write()`, `boost::asio::buffers_begin()` because one of their arguments was also in the `boost::asio` namespace.  Regardless, I have modified the example to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed I could compile those lines even without using boost::asio::ip::tcp;